# 'i' symbol in TeX

Tags: symbols

Consider:

[image]

I would like to know the LaTeX command for the symbol above. I searched for it online and tried [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but I could not find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{i}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One drawback, of course is that the bbm fonts are bitmapped.  There is a scalable alternative with the STIX fonts, but it looks slightly different.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\bbi}{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stixbb}{m}{n}i}}

\begin{document}

$\bbi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I know why you not recommend about the `\mathbb` tag? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi That only has blackboard bold capital letters (ABC…), not lowercase (ABC…).

Comment: (For the confused, my comment above was written on my phone which autocorrected 'abc' to 'ABC' rather unhelpfully.)

Answer (score 11):

If you have the option to use unicode math, you can also use `\Bbbi` (U+1D55A) or `\mitBbbi` (U+02148) for the italic one (Thanks to Ingmar who pointed this out). Below you see the result in some of the commonly used fonts. If the font does not have it a question mark is shown.

[image: many different i]

Comment: Isn't it U+2148, though? And that's DOUBLE-STRUCK **ITALIC** SMALL I, which may or may not be what OP needs.

Comment: Thanks Ingmar! I should not write answers before breakfast.

Answer (score 6):

There is Unicode character U+1D55A (MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK SMALL I). If you
use a TeX-engine that allows you to use arbitrary fonts (like `LuaLaTeX`) and have a font that supports the glyph, you could use  directly, as it were.